# Nuxt not creating dist directory

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, nuxt.js

I use `docker-compose` to build and run an SSR Nuxt.JS application. Web server is `nginx`.

I cannot use nginx reverse proxy to run this application, because directory `dist` is not created in `/app/`. This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:14.17.0-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN apk add python make g++
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build
ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
ENV PORT 3000
ENV NODE_ENV production
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

It does not work. But If I run this command in my docker host path `/home/path/project-1/` (the path Nuxt.JS files exist):

```
yarn start
```

I can temporarily see the application via:

```
http://ip:3000
```

I searched and tried some solutions, but none of them worked (unfortunately).

This is the log when I run `yarn start` in my terminal:

```
yarn run v1.22.11
$ nuxt start
ℹ [HPM] Proxy created: /api/  -> https://api.site.com/api
ℹ [HPM] Proxy rewrite rule created: "^/api/" ~> ""

   ╭───────────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                           │
   │   Nuxt.js @ v2.14.3                       │
   │                                           │
   │   ▸ Environment: production               │
   │   ▸ Rendering:   server-side              │
   │   ▸ Target:      server                   │
   │                                           │
   │   Memory usage: 32.7 MB (RSS: 105 MB)     │
   │                                           │
   │   Listening: http://ip:3000/   │
   │                                           │
   ╰───────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

What is wrong for running?

The reason I cannot proxy pass it to nginx is that there's no document root. If I use `#` at the beginning of `root` directive, I use this error in `nginx`:

```
2021/10/14 12:02:29 [error] 25#25: *180 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: my_ip, server: app.site.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "app.site.com"
2021/10/14 12:02:29 [error] 25#25: *181 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: my_ip, server: app.site.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "app.site.com", referrer: "https://app.
```

**Update 1**

As said kissu, this is the related block in `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
  target: 'server',
  server: {
    port: 3000, // default: 3000
    host: '0.0.0.0', // default: localhost
  },
```

Comment: There's a lot of things happening here. Let's narrow down the issue a bit. What is your `target` in `nuxt.config.js`?

Comment: @kissu I added to the question

Comment: So, what happens when you `yarn build`? Don't you see a `dist` directory at the root of your project?

Comment: @kissu the dev says there should be a `.nuxt` directory and there should be no `dist` directory. When I run `yarn build`, it creates `.nuxt` and when I change nginx config document root from `/app/dist` to `/app/.nuxt`, the website works fine. I should investigate more but that's a workaround or solution (not sure which one could be).

Comment: `.nuxt` is used only for dev purposes. For production, you need to have a `dist` otherwise it will not be optimized at all.

Comment: @kissu really? Thanks for that. I did not find any docs related to `dist` folder for SSR Production. Would you please give me that? And could you share links that what I should do to create `dist`? I did not find any websites telling that.

Comment: Oh no, I failed on this one. `.nuxt` is also used for `server` while `dist` is used for `static`. This will be normalized with Nuxt3. Meanwhile, if you `yarn build`, it will create it in `.nuxt` as shown here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/get-started/commands#server-deployment

Comment: @kissu thanks a lot. The application runs fine with `/app/.nuxt` path. I think my question was wrong because of your explanations (regarding `dist` and `.nuxt` directories).

Comment: So, is your issue fixed?!

Comment: @kissu yes that is fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `yarn build` and targeting `/app/.nuxt` fixed the issue.